# Why do I need a type for my vector in my function parameter c++

Tags: c++, vector

Hey guys when I compile my code I get several errors which I dont understand. One of the error tells me that vector is not a type but I had defined it as a float type which is showing as `const vector<float>& vector` Another error tells me I cannot convert to an int but I don't see anywhere in the program where I have declared a type int for a variable or vector. Here are my errors and code:

```
prog.cpp:5:58: error: 'vector' is not a type
 static void AutoCorrelation(const vector<float>& vector, vector<float>& autoCorrelationOut, float& autoCorrelationFactorOut);
                                                          ^
prog.cpp:5:64: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token
 static void AutoCorrelation(const vector<float>& vector, vector<float>& autoCorrelationOut, float& autoCorrelationFactorOut);
                                                                ^
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:16:38: error: cannot convert 'std::vector<float>' to 'int' for argument '2' to 'void AutoCorrelation(const std::vector<float>&, int)'
  AutoCorrelation(vec1,vec2,factor_out);
                                      ^
prog.cpp: At global scope:
prog.cpp:20:51: error: 'vector' is not a type
 void AutoCorrelation(const vector<float>& vector, vector<float>& autoCorrelationOut, float& autoCorrelationFactorOut)
                                                   ^
prog.cpp:20:57: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token
 void AutoCorrelation(const vector<float>& vector, vector<float>& autoCorrelationOut, float& autoCorrelationFactorOut)

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

static void AutoCorrelation(const vector<float>& vector, vector<float>& autoCorrelationOut, float& autoCorrelationFactorOut);
    int main() {

    vector<float> vec1,vec2;
    float factor_out=10.02f;
    float a,b,c=1.00f;

    vec1.push_back(a);
    vec1.push_back(b);
    vec2.push_back(c);
    AutoCorrelation(vec1,vec2,factor_out);
    return 0;
}

void AutoCorrelation(const vector<float>& vector, vector<float>& autoCorrelationOut, float& autoCorrelationFactorOut)
{

}
```

Comment: Fast fix: Do not apply "using namespace std;"

Comment: @DieterLücking that doesn't make a difference in the problem that I'm dealing with though I guess it would make it run faster

Comment: Groan. Kindly refer to my avatar

Comment: @I_love_coding_93 How would not doing `using namespace std;` *make it run faster* ???

Comment: Please don't rename the `vector`.  Use a different name, like 'vector_of_floats`.  This may make your issues go away.

Comment: You have at least 36^32 possible characters to use for identifier names.  Please don't name your variables the same as types (case insensitive).  If you want a synonym, try using `typedef`.

Comment: @I_love_coding_93 - I'd be willing to bet that Dieter's suggestion to get rid of `using namespace std;` would fix this problem; after you do that, the name of the argument type is `std::vector<float>`, and an argument named `vector` son't interfere.

Comment: And since running code reaches completion sooner than non-running code, it follows that removing `using namespace std` indeed makes the code run faster. Q.E.D.

Comment: Wow. And here I had my money on Pixies. Pixies can run the hamster wheel in the CPU at a higher clockrate than the usual goblins.

Answer (score 7):

Look carefully at the argument list for `AutoCorrelation`. After `const vector<float>& vector`, the name `vector` refers to an object.

Comment: It is interesting that the language does this since you cannot use the parameters for anything else in the parameter list

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes and no, it's consistent with the rest of the language (e.g. `int x = x;` this doesnt make sense but after `int x`, the `x` symbol is introduced as being an int variable, which is essentially what happens here).

Comment: @Borgleader True.  I guess it is better to to add exceptions to the rules.